# Return an Array in a Button function on VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I have a button event that saves the content of a textbox to an array, each time the button is pressed it saves to the next position. But when i call the array in another function i only get 0's as the values in the array. Here is my button code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click  
    ReDim ArX(i)  
    ArX(i) = Val(txtX.Text)  
    txtXl.Text = txtXl.Text & ArX(i) & "~"  
    i = i + 1  
    txtX.Text = ""  
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't use an array for this. Use a list of strings. Welcome to the 21st century.

Comment: whats wrong with using an Array? im using it for handling a list of numbers. Im geniously curious since if there is a way i can optimize my program im glad to learn

Comment: You _rarely_ need to use raw arrays in .NET - there are many collection types that handle lists of information for you in much easier to use ways.  For instance you could declare `ArX` as a `List(Of Integer)`.  You won't need to `ReDim` it - you just call `.Add()`.

Comment: Arrays are good for fixed lenght data, they are terrible for adding or removing values. Even in vb6 the redim statement was considered as somthing to avoid. The .Net framework provide us better collections to use.

Comment: if i were to make a List(Of Integer) then would i still need to return the values? if then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are correct.  You should use a List(Of T ) when dealing with these collections that dynamically grow.  It'll be more efficient than your current implementation since it will not reallocate every time the button is pressed.  As for why your implementation has issues, you're using Redim which pretty much creates a new Array instance.  If using Redim, you need to use the Preserve keyword to have the existing items copied.  Again, this is very inefficient.  List(Of T) is an easier API and will be more efficient.